# % width of what part does this <div> take

Tags: css, html, width, percentage

So there might be an easier way to explain this problem but this is how I know:

This basically is a simple dropdown menu inside a dropdown menu. I know how this dropdown works but the real problem here is width of .

```
        <div id="nav2">
            Categories
            <div id="dropcontents">
                <div id="sub-nav">
                    Mobile
                    <div id="sub-dropcontents">
                        <a href="#">Hardware</a>
                        <a href="#">Software</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Windows</a>
                <a href="#">News</a>
                <a href="#">Articles</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now the question is if I give 50% width to "dropcontents" then it takes like the half the whole website width. SO isn't it supposed to take 50% of "nav2" as it is inside that div? And I don't want to use pixel here. And I noted that "sub-dropcontents" take 50% width of "dropcontents" which I assume is correct.

Here's the pictorial representation:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `position` value:

If the parent and the children are not positioned, 50% width for the children means 50% width of the parent

If the children is `position:absolute;` 50% of width means 50% of the first parent that is positioned; if there is not any parent it'll refer the percentage to the whole document.

To fix that just put `position:something;` in the `div` that the percentage must refer to.

For a better explanation see this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/8d2emo6x/4/)**.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.absolute {
  position:absolute;
}
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
Parent-> not positioned and Child -> not positioned
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
Parent-> not positioned and Child -> absolute
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child absolute">
  </div>
</div>
Parent-> relative and Child -> absolute
<div class="parent relative">
  <div class="child absolute">
  </div>
</div>
Parent-> absolute and Child -> absolute
<div class="parent absolute">
  <div class="child absolute">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it fixed it. Turns out I have got to see more tutorials on positioning. Is it necessary to position parent div to absolute inorder for its children to get the width according to the parent?

Comment: Yeah, the parents just need to be positioned.

Answer (score 0):

it(any element) takes the percentage width of its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Note `nav2` is a block element and it will take out the entire width of of its parent (in this case the body)

See this snippet

```css
#nav2{
    border:solid red;

    }
    #dropcontents{
      border:solid;
      width:50%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav2">
  Categories
  <div id="dropcontents">
    <div id="sub-nav">
      Mobile
      <div id="sub-dropcontents">
        <a href="#">Hardware</a>
        <a href="#">Software</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Windows</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Articles</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you set the width of nav to to 50% of its parent width, you will notice that the `dropContents` div will adjust to 50% of `nav2`

See snippet below

```css
#nav2 {
  border: solid red;
  width: 50%
}
#dropcontents {
  border: solid;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav2">
  Categories
  <div id="dropcontents">
    <div id="sub-nav">
      Mobile
      <div id="sub-dropcontents">
        <a href="#">Hardware</a>
        <a href="#">Software</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Windows</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Articles</a>
  </div>
</div>
```